# Deploying Keras model on Arduino: Specifying input dimensions of Neural net

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I'm trying to detect specific movements using IMU's (accelerometer + gyro) using neural net's.

I have created Neural net in google colab (python + keras), and have successfully converted it into .h file.

Neural net has 18 inputs, and 1 output (output = 1/0)

I'm having trouble specifying input dimensions in C code (arduino).
The code compiles, runs, but the neural net's output I get is not correct!

When I try to test input dimensions of neural net in C code, I get the following result:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoKuo.png

**Dim 1 size shows 1, but shouldn't "Dim 1 size" be 18??**

Thank you for all your answers!

Answer (score 0):

In the model you created in Keras, the input value of the first layer appears as 1.

Solution suggestion:

To test your project in google colab you should do this model.predict(x1,x2,x3,...,x18). If this test is successful, you should examine the data sent by the device that assigns the model_input variable. The order may be incorrect during the assignment of this variable.

best regards

Comment: Hello, first, thank you for your answer!
In keras, I specifyed input_size(18,), and even tried input_dim(18).
In keras, I can sucessfully test my Neural net, by passing new data into the NN. It's output on new data suggests, it is trained correctly (only detect specific movements, see pictures)

Picture 1:   https://ibb.co/3SKZb5h
Picture 2:   https://ibb.co/ym2TFx0

Comment: Also, I'm in Google Colab, I'm testing NN with model.predict(DATA), where DATA is matrix of size 18x10,000 (10,000 samples), and it seems to work in colab, but I still have no clue how to properly pass array of 18x40 to input tensor in arduino [C]

Comment: Shouldn't the value entered to model_input in ardunio be 18x1?
if you can, try setting up a for loop of 40 rows with 18 and sending them to the model separately.

If you say this will not work for you, set the input_dim to be (18,40) so it will work in Arduino. But I cannot guarantee that it will give you accurate results.

If your sensors are producing continuous data then I suggest you to use the LSTM layer because you are doing a time series analysis and LSTM is generally good at time series analysis.

Comment: Hello,
thank you for your answer!!
I've tried entering only 18x1 array into input tensor in arduino, but it still does not work..

I've tried input_dim=720 ( that is 18*40), but than the keras model does not want to train, since my training data is 18x8000...
Entering input shape(18,40) does not work, since the train data is 18x8000...

I have tried for loop to enter 720 informations into input tensor, and the output from NN is not correct...

Sincerely,

Comment: Hello, Have you tried training the model in google colab and exporting it and importing this file in ardunio?

I want to understand that do you do the training on ardunio or do you want to run the training on ardunio using a model that has been trained?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BzzqYNYOcWc

Maybe this video can be of use to you.

Comment: Hello,
I trained my model in google colab, and exported .h file to arduino.
I've actually watched and followed this exact video you've sent, hehe :)
This video is the reason I got this far XD..